# Bitcoind doesn't find transactions / synchronize / update until last block from Testnet

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, testnet, faucets

I set up bitcoind as server. It downloads the testnet blockchain but it is inconsistent with public data:

```
http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/q/getblockcount 

182951 (As of 18/02/14)
```

And

```
bitcoind getblockcount 

53317
```

My testnet accounts receive bitcoins from public faucets:

http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/address/mjDutNstJpZo929nLdZGKPh75fWKuTQNi1  (form 2 different faucets)

But

```
bitcoind listreceivedbyaddress 0 true
[ 
...
{
        "address" : "mjDutNstJpZo929nLdZGKPh75fWKuTQNi1",
        "account" : "3",
        "label" : "3",
        "amount" : 0.00000000,
        "confirmations" : 0
    }
]
```

Any help?

```
bitcoind getinfo
{
    "version" : 32400,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 53317,
    "connections" : 2,
    "proxy" : "",
    "generate" : false,
    "genproclimit" : -1,
    "difficulty" : 0.55300531,
    "hashespersec" : 0,
    "testnet" : true,
    "keypoololdest" : 1392632512,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

**Solution**

Please read the accepted answer.

Dont do apt-get update and install (at least in Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS)

Instead:

```
sudo aptitude install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install bitcoind
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using **version 0.3.24** of the bitcoin client, which is *extremely* old (released July of 2011).  The **latest version is 0.8.6**.

Versions prior to 0.7.0 (released April of 2012) used a different testnet blockchain (called testnet2), which is no longer in general use.  Since 0.7.0, everyone uses testnet3, which has a new genesis block and a separate block chain.  So the coins you received are waiting in that new chain, but you're looking at the old one.

**Upgrade to the latest version of bitcoind**.  Then copy your `wallet.dat` from `.bitcoin/testnet2` to `.bitcoin/testnet3`.  After synchronization, you should see your coins (and avoid a lot of other issues too).

I'm actually pretty surprised your client found enough testnet2 peers to get a complete copy of the testnet2 block chain!